# I cant seem to make my project readable on more my own computer screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build my first portfolio page here . This is my second ever thing I have coded. Just started 3 days ago.

I tried to build the page with minimal code copying. Used as much stuff as I could remember from the courses I have taken so far this week.

So I can seem to make this page fit on all screen resolutions. Everything distorts and moves around.

Help is much appreciated thank you.

https://codepen.io/Grumpusjiujitsu/pen/YQeZyo

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-
awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div style="clear: both;">
<div class="header">

  <h class="name" style="color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 50px"> 
  Aaron Jabs
    <a src="#" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-
551554_960_720.jpg" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank;"></a>
    <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-
551554_960_720.jpg" class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank;"></a>
    <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-
551554_960_720.jpg" class="fa fa-youtube" target="_blank;"></a>
  </h>
  <h1 class="alignleft" style="font-size: 40px;"> Software Developer </h1>
  <h1 class="alignright" style="font-size: 20px; word-spacing: 13px"><a 
href="#">About</a> <a href="#">Portfolio</a> <a href="#">Contact</a></h1>
</div>
</div>

<p class="portfoliotitle" style="text-align: center;"> Portfolio </p>

<div class="firstrow">
<div class="puppyport">
  <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/54/pug-
690566_960_720.jpg" target=" _blank"><img 
src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/54/pug-690566_960_720.jpg" 
alt="a puppy" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    <p style="text-align: center;">A puppy App for Android </p>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="kittyport">
  <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/31/12/36/cat-
618470_960_720.jpg" target=" _blank"><img 
src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/31/12/36/cat-618470_960_720.jpg" 
alt="a kitty" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    <p style="text-align: center;">A kitty App for iOS</p>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="secondrow">
  <div class="bunnyport">
    <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/09/18/02/01/bunny-
183301_960_720.jpg" target=" _blank"><img 
src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/09/18/02/01/bunny-
183301_960_720.jpg" alt="a puppy" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
      <p style="text-align: center;">A bunny App for WP</p>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="duckport">
    <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/29/13/08/goose-
379393_960_720.jpg" target=" _blank"><img 
src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/29/13/08/goose-
379393_960_720.jpg" alt="a kitty" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
      <p style="text-align: center;">Ducky App available on iOS and 
Android</p>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="thirdrow">
    <div class="war">
      <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/02/06/34/war-
469503_960_720.jpg" target=" _blank"><img 
src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/02/06/34/war-469503_960_720.jpg" 
alt="a puppy" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
        <p style="text-align: center;">An App that simulates War</p>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="cancer">
      <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/10/20/48/medic-
563425_960_720.jpg" target=" _blank"><img 
src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/10/20/48/medic-
563425_960_720.jpg" alt="a kitty" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
        <p style="text-align: center;">An App that cures Cancer</p>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


.header {
padding: 25px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #669999;
}

.alignright {
float: right;
}

.fa-facebook {
color: #3b5998;
}

.fa-twitter {
 color: #0084b4;
}

.fa-youtube {
color: #cc2900;
}

.portfoliotitle {
padding-top: 50px;
padding-right: 50%;
padding-left: 50%;
}

.puppyport {
padding-left: 245px;
float: left;
}

.kittyport {
padding-right: 245px;
float: right;
}

.firstrow {
padding-top: 30px;
}

.bunnyport {
padding-left: 245px;
float: left;
}

.duckport {
padding-right: 245px;
float: right;
}

.secondrow {
 padding-top: 30px;
}

.war {
padding-left: 245px;
float: left;
}

.cancer {
padding-right: 245px;
float: right;
}

.thirdrow {
padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Ok so first of all, read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Secondly, I suggest that you start something from scratch to understand whats going on. There's too many code involved here and theres no point of making that working if you don't master the basics. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

first of all, responsive webdesign is tricky and takes some practice. But there are a few things to understand before writing responsive CSS-code.

**Percent values**

As I see, you already started using percent values in your CSS. While values with `%` are relative to their parent, you can use `vw` (viewport width) and `vh` (viewport height) to specify values relative to the browser window's size.

**Media queries**

Sometimes percent values are not enough, for example in the "images-section" on your example page. You should try to use [media-queries](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries) to define a break-point and change the CSS specification whenever the browser size is less or more than that breakpoint. In your special case around 1100px would be a could break point to change the `float`-direction of your images and to center them. Or simply reduce the left- or right-padding value at this breakpoint to keep them longer in one line.

Taking courses and reading books is always a good start to get comfortable with the technology, but you should always try to build little things, in many cases you will despair at first, but you should always try to find a solution, even if it is not the most elegant one.